# change style of navigationbar and toolbar in Quick Look Framework in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am use Quick Look Framework in Iphone. I want to change style of navigationbar and toolbar of Quick Look Framework controller.  Is it possible in Iphone ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried making use of the appearance proxy?

Comment: yes, But I have tried with inbuild property.  But there is not any property like that in which I can change style of Quick Look Framework controller.